# How to wake up an Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application in which I click:

Menu -> Catalogue -> Product Group -> Product Detail (where I click "Add to cart" and open the Cart) -> Cart (where I click "Save cart")

Cart Activity is then `finish()`-ed and Product Group is shown. But I want Menu Activity to be shown.

Should I just use
`Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
startActivity(intent);`

to open the menu, or is there a possibility to wake Menu Activity up.

Hope it's clear :)

EDIT 2010/12/15

This is call from Cart Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

and it closes the application :(

**SOLVED 2010/12/17**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
//          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Don't forget to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` into the manifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an Intent aimed at your Menu activity with the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag set.